# Python Cassandra Datastax driver queries have no effect

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, cql

I am using the Cassandra Datastax driver to execute a delete query and it has no effect on the db. When I run the exact same query through cqlsh it works fine.

```
DEL_QUERY = "DELETE FROM x.user_data WHERE username='{0}' AND usertype = 17;".format(NEW_ID)
    logger.debug("Query:\n %r", DEL_QUERY)
    cluster = Cluster([CASSANDRA_HOST], port=CASSANDRA_PORT, cql_version=CASSANDRA_CQL_VERSION, auth_provider=CASSANDRA_AUTH_PROVIDER, protocol_version=3)
    session = cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE)
    logger.debug("Executing Query:\n" + DEL_QUERY)
    if not test_run:
        session.execute(DEL_QUERY)

    logger.debug("Query Executed.") 
    cluster.shutdown()
```

Results of the following code in terminal:

```
2017-03-27 18:30:10,588 - del - Executing Query:
 "DELETE FROM x.user_data WHERE username='9999999999' AND usertype = 17"
2017-03-27 18:30:10,630 - del - Query Executed.
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I format my query string?

(I have now wrapped the query in a try/except and it does not print the exception message)

Comment: Can you share the query string after format interpolation?

Comment: `"DELETE FROM x.user_data WHERE username='9999999999' AND usertype = 17"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have problem with "formatting" the query.

1. Print DEL_QUERY after formatting and see/execute it in cqlsh.
2. Try to execute hard-coded query from python, without formatting.